# Where can I find a comparison of mathematical subjects taught for primary and secondary school around the world?

Tags: curriculum

I have been searching this for a long time, but most of what I find spends more time on cultural aspects and what is expected from the teacher, etc. Perhaps this is really trivial to find, but I am Brazilian and maybe I am googling for it with the wrong terms (sometimes I think that my translation suits adequately but end up discovering that no one uses that expression for what I tried to say). I tried: "International mathematics curricula comparison" and similar stuff, but what I found was not very helpful.

Comment: I think that this is a hard question to answer. I looked for similar information. There is a field called "comparative education", but it seems very fragmented from what I can tell (and also very theory-encumbered).

Comment: One difficulty is that very few people know more than two or three systems (or languages) well enough to say anything meaningful. I would look for information about comparisons of teaching of specific topics. For example the algorithms taught for performing basic arithmetic, e.g subtraction and long division, vary from country to country. Lots has been written about this (in part becuase it is a real practical problem in contexts in which there are students from many countries). Comparing something like curricula is much harder - e.g. uniform curricula don't always exist (for example, USA).

Comment: Learn Esperanto, and then use the Esperanto delegate service to make your inquiry.